# Canon 600D Autofocus not working when using view finder but working in live-view

Tags: autofocus, viewfinder, canon-600d

My Canon 600D's autofocus is not working at all when using the view finder.

When I use it in live-view mode the autofocus works fine.

I tried to google but could not find anything concrete.

Any advice?

Comment: Jello Pranet, welcome to Photo.SE. Which lens are you using ? Have you try with an other one ? Please edit your question to add those details, they seem relevant.

Comment: The possible answers to your question are heavily dependent upon which lens you are using. Without this information it is very difficult to answer your question.

Comment: it is happening irrespective of the lens that i use :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofocus in life view and through the viewfinder use different technologies. In live view, the camera tries to get the best contrast for the image. The viewfinder AF uses the phase detection technology which includes special hardware in your camera.

If the viewfinder-AF does not work, you may have a hardware issue with your camera. Or you may have put your lens in manual mode (well I suppose, this would also disable AF in live-view).

Your dealer could help you in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try and see if that can be fixed!